# What causes the wallet functions to be disabled?

Tags: bitcoind, wallet, api, ubuntu

I have run bitcoind as a server on one host. On a second host, I have configured bitcoin-cli to interact with bitcoind.  However, all wallet commands are now disabled with this new configuration.  When I run simple commands such as:

```
bitcoin-cli listaccounts
```

or

```
bitcoin-cli getaccountaddress "new_account"
```

I get:

```
error: {"code":-32601,"message":"Method not found (disabled)"}
```

When I call any other bitcoin-cli method that does not involve wallets, I get a normal response.

What is happening?  What causes the wallet functionality to be disabled?

The configuration file reads as follows:

```
server=1
rpcuser=jared
rpcpassword=1234
rpcport=8332
rpcallowip=192.168.0.0/16
gen=0
prune=600
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Bitcoin Core 0.11 pruning is experimental, and incompatible with the wallet.

So turning on the `prune=` option automatically disables the wallet function.

In 0.12 the wallet will work with pruning (though you obviously won't be able to rescan past the pruning cutoff).

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful information! Problem is now fixed.